# what does this cmd 'source' do with kubectl?

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I'm doing a lab and can't understand this:

> Kubectl has support for auto-completion allowing you to discover the
> available options. This is applied to the current terminal session
> with source <(kubectl completion bash)

The cmd:

```
source <(kubectl completion bash)
```

sources-in what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `source` (synonym for `.`) is a bash built in command which executes the given file in the current shell environment
- `<(command ...)` is process substitution - the output of the commands are passed as a file
- bash completion is implemented with shell functions, which must be set in the current shell environment
- You can view the code that's executed to set up the completion functions: `kubectl completion bash`

Answer (score 0):

Read and execute the generated completion script (kubectl completion bash) in your current shell.

Answer (score 0):

Using *source*, it runs within the existing shell, any variables/functions created or modified will remain available after the command completes.

In contrast you just run just the command, then a separate subshell would be spawned to run the command. When the command ends, you will not see the variables/functions in the current shell.

`<( expression )` will attach the output of `expression` to the stdin of an application/program.

So the command will run `kubectl completion bash` within the existing shell instead of a separate subshell.